# Loading a vala libraries css the moment a component of that library is instantiated

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I am currently working on a vala library containing several GTK based GUI objects.

As i test it, I just compile it as a standard application and run it from a main class, in this I load the css this way:

```
private void load_css(){
        Gtk.CssProvider css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
        css_provider.load_from_path (stylesheetpath);
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen (Gdk.Screen.get_default (), css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    }
```

And it works just as it should. But I am wondering then, can I make certain this css is applied, automatically, if this is compiled as a library and then used in another project?

Comment: What is wrong with exposing the css loading function as a public method in your library interface? I wouldn't just implicitly load CSS, which could lead to odd behavior.

Comment: Well I just assumed that one would want to make certain it loaded, so that everything looked proper. What about placing the CSS in the compiled library somehow? I mean it's currently in .css files in the project structure, but it doesn't get compiled into the binary after all.